# Mouse the focus to an object using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

I am automating a website using selenium RC and python 2.7 on Ubuntu Linux. Here is what I need to do:

Go to the site http://borro.com.
Scroll down to the bottom of the page using key down native command
I need to hover the mouse on g +1 
read the tool tip
click on the name that appears in the tool tip.

The problem I am having is -- I need the mouse to physically move there, wait for say 2 secs and then read the tool tip and click on the name

The mouse is not physically moving there and I think the focus is lost and it says element xpath not found.   [image]

Answer (score 3):

We've solved a lot of our focus issues by sending a blank key to the element so it gets focused. In this case, you'd probably want to send blank key to the tooltip as soon as it appears. I'm familiar with webdriver but not RC, but RC should have something like send_key(element_xpath, " ") as well.

To get the tooltip's xpath, you can use firebug, and in the console, use something like

```
$x("//*[contains(text(), 'Publicly recommend this as')]")
```

to make sure this element is found and xpath is correct. I also recommend not using wildcard characters, so once you find the tooltip's xpath, try to replace the * by the actual element type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just for the record: I managed to solve focus issues by doing `button.click()` instead of `form.submit()` in python code (where `button` and `form` are `WebElement` instances).

Answer (score 1):

Button Xpath and on hover on button xpath are given below

```
   Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement tagElement = driver.findElement(By.id("button"));
   builder.moveToElement(tagElement).build().perform();

         /html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div
```

Try:

```
          selenium.mouseOver("mylocator");
```

Comment: Ankit, Thanls. However I am using selenium RC and not webdriver. Can you pl suggest a solution with selenium RC?