# Scroll until button is present on the screen

Tags: python, selenium

I have looked at similar posts about waiting for an element to be present, but I could not find anything that is specific to my question. Right now I have the scrolling portion down, and I want to click a button once it is shown on the display screen, not just wait for the element to be present, but for the user to be able to see the button on the screen once it scrolled to it.

I tried using `is_displayed()` because I thought it would return True once the element of the button is shown on the screen, but it doesn't seem to be the call I am looking for.

I also tried extracting the `fill` attribute to check the hex-code, but didn't seem to recognize it.

```
for i in range(1000):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1))
    # print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("QBdPU")).is_displayed()
    # print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("QBdPU")).get_attribute("fill")
```

Here is the HTML code from the page

```
<button class="wpO6b " type="button">
<div class="QBdPU ">
   <span class="">
      <svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" 
       viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24"><path d="M34.6 6.1c5.7 0 10.4 5.2 10.4 11.5 
       0 6.8-5.9 11-11.5 16S25 41.3 24 41.9c-1.1-.7-4.7-4-9.5-8.3-5.7-5-11.5-9.2- 
       11.5-16C3 11.3 7.7 6.1 13.4 6.1c4.2 0 6.5 2 8.1 4.3 1.9 2.6 2.2 3.9 2.5 
       3.9.3 0 .6-1.3 2.5-3.9 1.6-2.3 3.9-4.3 8.1-4.3m0-3c-4.5 0-7.9 1.8-10.6 
       5.6-2.7-3.7-6.1-5.5-10.6-5.5C6 3.1 0 9.6 0 17.6c0 7.3 5.4 12 10.6 16.5.6.5 
       1.3 1.1 1.9 1.7l2.3 2c4.4 3.9 6.6 5.9 7.6 6.5.5.3 1.1.5 1.6.5.6 0 1.1-.2 
       1.6-.5 1-.6 2.8-2.2 7.8-6.8l2-1.8c.7-.6 1.3-1.2 2-1.7C42.7 29.6 48 25 48 
       17.6c0-8-6-14.5-13.4-14.5z"></path>
      </svg> 
   </span>
</div>
</div>
```

Any advice on moving forward would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250908/mouse-the-focus-to-an-object-using-selenium-python) will help

Comment: Please copy and paste the HTML into your post. It does not need to be the full html. Just a small representative sample will work.

Comment: @GregBurghardt My mistake, I copy pasted the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Once the button is present on the page, you can scroll it into view with this piece of code:

```
    button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_button)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", button)
```